# How to close window on click outside(angular)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I found on youtube how to create a directive that closes the window by clicking outside the window. But it is not working properly in my project. I created simple toDoList application and added the ability to rename task. So when I click the button, the edit window is created. The problem is that when i click on the div with class "tasks", this window doesn't close(clicking elsewhere works correctly).
Here is directive:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Inject, OnDestroy, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription, filter, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickedOutside]'
})
export class ClickedOutsideDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy   {
  @Output() public clickedOutside = new EventEmitter<void>();

  documentClickSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.documentClickSubscription = fromEvent(this.document, 'click').pipe(
      filter((event) => {
        return !this.isInside(event?.target as HTMLElement)
      })
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.clickedOutside.emit();
    })
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.documentClickSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
  isInside(elementToCheck: HTMLElement): boolean {
    return elementToCheck === this.element.nativeElement || this.element.nativeElement.contains(elementToCheck);
  }
}
```

My TS is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../../Shared/Interfaces/interfaces';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { StorageService } from '../../Shared/Services/storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-to-do-list',
  templateUrl: './to-do-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './to-do-list.component.scss'
})
export class ToDoListComponent implements OnInit {
  taskForm!: FormGroup;
  tasksArray: any[] = [];
  showMoreArray: boolean[] = [];
  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.taskForm = new FormGroup({
      taskValue: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    })
    this.tasksArray = this.storageService.getTasks() || [];
    this.showMoreArray = new Array(this.tasksArray.length).fill(false);
  }
  addTask(text: string) {
    const task: Task = {
      value: text,
      isComplete: false
    };
    this.tasksArray.push(task);
    this.taskForm.reset();
    this.storageService.setTasksArray(this.tasksArray);
  }
  changeStatus(task: Task) {
    task.isComplete = !task.isComplete;
    this.storageService.setTasksArray(this.tasksArray)
  }
  closeEditing(){
    this.showMoreArray.fill(false);
  }
  
  deleteTask(index: number) {
    this.tasksArray.splice(index, 1);
    this.storageService.setTasksArray(this.tasksArray);
  }
  renameTask(newTaskText: string, index: number) {
    if (newTaskText != '') {
      this.tasksArray[index].value = newTaskText;
      this.storageService.setTasksArray(this.tasksArray);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  saveEditing(newTaskText: string, index: number) {
    this.renameTask(newTaskText, index);
    
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="taskForm" (ngSubmit)="addTask(taskField.value)" class="tasksForm">
    <input formControlName="taskValue" type="text" name="task" id="task" placeholder="Enter task" #taskField>
    <button type="submit">Add task</button>
</form>
<div class="showTasks" *ngIf="tasksArray && tasksArray.length > 0; then tasks else noTasks"></div>
<ng-template #tasks>
    <div class="tasks" appClickedOutside (clickedOutside)="closeEditing()">
        <div *ngFor="let task of tasksArray; let idx = index" class="task">
            <input type="checkbox" #isDone (change)="changeStatus(task)" [checked]="task.isComplete">
            <div class="rightSide">
                <div class="taskText">
                    <p [style.color]="isDone.checked ? 'red' : 'black'">{{task.value}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="btnDiv" (click)="showMoreArray[idx] = !showMoreArray[idx]" >
                    <span class="moreBtn"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="editingTask" *ngIf="showMoreArray[idx]">
                    <label for="newTask">Rename:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="newTask" id="newTask" placeholder="Rename task:" class="renameField"
                        #newTask>
                    <button type="button" class="deleteBtn"
                        (click)="deleteTask(idx); showMoreArray[idx] = !showMoreArray[idx]">Delete</button>
                    <div class="changesBtn">
                        <button type="button" class="cancelBtn"
                            (click)="showMoreArray[idx] = !showMoreArray[idx]">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="Save" class="saveBtn"
                            (click)="saveEditing(newTask.value, idx); showMoreArray[idx] = !showMoreArray[idx]">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #noTasks>
    No tasks yet!
</ng-template>
```

Maybe someone could help to deal with this.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: My guess is that you're clicking a button, and since the button is also outside the modal, it's being closed before it has opened